# How to export data table results in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

In my application we are using primefaces 6.0, here we are having one data table. To export that table values we are using primefaces data exporter.

In that table am having one column value has hyperlink, on click of the hyperlink we will display some data in model panel.

Now what is my issue is , at the time of export, i want to export the content what i am showing in the model panel instead of hyperlink. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Only way is by writing a custom exporter

Comment: The following links can help you accomplish that: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/expandableTable.jsf and https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/showcase/util/ExcelCustomExporter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by CSS styles, i know the data to export, That is in my current object so i have added in output label and applied style as display none. when i export, the display none output label data exported.

```
 <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        Header
    </f:facet>
    <p:commandLink styleClass="linkStyle" action="#{controller.opendialog(tc.optTagInfo)}">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tc.optTagInfo}"  style="display:none;"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```